# Cosa sono i "caracuzzi"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> TWENTYONE, i due vecchi innamorati s’arrendevano alla gioventú, tanto gli avevano dato una bella lezione, adesso l’annunciatore vestito a stelle e strisce urlava e incitava la folla superstite a partecipare all’ultima dolorosa selezione: Diamante e Vita alzarono gli occhi e s’accorsero di essere rimasti soli a vedersela con un cameriere di Ocean Avenue e sua moglie, una creola zezzuta, le cui tette flosce come **caracuzzi** cercavano con successo di raggiungere l’ombelico, poi l’orchestrina attaccò l’ultimo valzer, Vita lo guardò negli occhi e un attimo prima dell’annuncio gli disse, sicura, abbiamo vinto, Diamà – FORTYFOUR, gridò l’uomo a stelle e strisce, and the winners are, the winners are... s’interruppe, perplesso, consultando il registro delle iscrizioni...

Qualcuno di voi saprebbe spiegare il significato di "caracuzzi"? Immagino si tratti di un vocabolo di uso regionale, possibilmente correlato al napoletano. Non ho trovato questo termine su nessun dizionario, neanche [sul vocabolario napoletano-italiano di Giuseppe Giacco né sul *Lessico e Letteratura del Dialetto Napoletano* di Salvatore Argenziano e Gianna De Filippis](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1397).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In un dizionario del dialetto gaetano, vale a dire di Gaeta, cittadina al confine tra Lazio e Campania (http://xoomer.virgilio.it/brguiz/gaeta/dizdiait.htm), *caracuzze* è il fico maturo che incomincia ad appassire e cade dall’albero. Il termine è usato in modo figurato.

Comment: L'ho trovato anche qui http://www.iststudiatell.org/rsc/annate_01/RSC_1969_5.pdf a p. 30

Comment: La zona geografica (dal punto di vista delle influenze dialettali) è la medesima, in effetti.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Quindi il vocaboli avrebbe origine semitica?

Comment: @Charo: Non mi azzarderei fin lì (bisognerebbe fare ricerche approfondite); segnalavo solo che Gaeta e Capua Vetere e Mondragone sono vicine.